# Can I ask a question that's already been asked by someone else but has not received any attention?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

My question has already been asked by someone else one month ago. But it has 14 views and no answers, Can I ask it again?

Or should I just upvote OP's question and hope for an answer in the future?

Comment: In general reasking duplicate questions should be avoided. You may try to edit the question to become more on focus and attract more attention. Successfully edited questions will be bumped up as active. Another way to draw attention is to place a bounty, as soon you have enough rep to do so.

Comment: When other advocate for edit and bounty.
There is possibility the old question is bad both in form, and containt.
It cannot be edited without changing 100% of the question. 

And you comes up with a simple exemple that will make the question clear and worthy. 

I do think that you should post the question, and mark the old one as a duplicate of the new one. 

But it would require having a good understaing of both question and beeing able to formulate an answer to the old one.

Comment: you can easly visualise an SQL question where original is a nonsens table with too mutch column that should be close as "no mcve". Op formulate his expected output with vague word without speaking of evident edge case that cause him to comes to SO. So you interpret Op needs and formulate it in a clear question with a MCVE, and clear edge case scenario and expected output for everyone of them. simplifying and generalising the problem, in a way that people having the same issue won't need to have a table and column exactly name as original question.